# Page doesn't scroll and text doesn't appear below the header, in the body

Tags: html, css

can someone please help me. I'm facing an issue where my page doesn't scroll down and the paragraphs don't appear in the body but on the header of my page. I have removed all unnecessary overflow elements from the CSS but that did not do anything.

https://codepen.io/arvindr2002/pen/oNzzMQb.
Thank you.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}

header {
    background-image: url(../images/Game.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right-side;
    position: fixed;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 5%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #E94B3CFF;
}
nav .logo {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
}
nav a:hover {
  border-top: 2px red;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  padding: 6px 0; 

}
nav .nav-area {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
nav .nav-area li {
    list-style: none;
}
nav .nav-area a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}
nav .icon-burger {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
nav .icon-burger .line {
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    nav .logo {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    nav .nav-area {             /* transforing toggle-bar */
        float: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 100px;
        bottom: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    nav .a {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    nav :checked ~ .nav-area {
        bottom: 0;
    }
    nav .icon-burger {
        display: block;
    }
    nav :checked ~ .icon-burger .line:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(10px) rotate(225deg);
    }
    nav :checked ~ .icon-burger .line:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-225deg);
    }
    nav :checked ~ .icon-burger .line:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
}
    
.welcome-text {
    position: fixed;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 25% 30%;
    text-align: center;
}
.welcome-text h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.welcome-text h1 span {
    color: #E94B3CFF;
}

.glow{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    margin: 10px 1;
    color: #E94B3CFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.5s;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 20px;
   
}
.glow:hover{
    background: #E94B3CFF;
    color: #050801;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #E94B3CFF,
                0 0 25px #E94B3CFF,
                0 0 50px #E94B3CFF,
                0 0 200px #E94B3CFF;
     -webkit-box-reflect:below 1px linear-gradient(transparent, #0005);
}

.glow span{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
.glow span:nth-child(1){
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,transparent,#E94B3CFF);
    animation: animate1 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate1{
    0%{
        left: -100%;
    }
    50%,100%{
        left: 100%;
    }
}
.glow span:nth-child(2){
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,transparent,#E94B3CFF);
    animation: animate2 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
@keyframes animate2{
    0%{
        top: -100%;
    }
    50%,100%{
        top: 100%;
    }
}
.glow span:nth-child(3){
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg,transparent,#E94B3CFF);
    animation: animate3 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.50s;
}
@keyframes animate3{
    0%{
        right: -100%;
    }
    50%,100%{
        right: 100%;
    }
}


.glow span:nth-child(4){
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg,transparent,#E94B3CFF);
    animation: animate4 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
@keyframes animate4{
    0%{
        bottom: -100%;
    }
    50%,100%{
        bottom: 100%;
    }
}/*resposive*/
```

Comment: remove `position: fixed` from `header`